# Where clause in Query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query looks like this. Suppose it was run well.im confused the last part of the **Where** clause.Can i write that from two different table?..how can i write it, cause i want to display those staff who a Active from that date range.

```
select d.Division,a.FirstName,
 (select count(h.id) from Department h
  inner join institution i on d.institution_id = i_Id
  ----
  ----
where i.institution_id =d.Id and h. date between @startDate and @endDate) as test

from Division d, inmate a
where d.Active = 1 and a.Active = 1
```

edited
i have edit my query and the final looks like this..

```
select d.DivisionName,a.FirstName, (select count(h.id) from InHistory h inner join Institution i on h.Institution_id = i.Id inner join InType it on h.InType_id = it.Id inner join mate a on h.mate_id = a.Id where i.InstitutionRegion_id = d.Id and it.InTypeName like '%Staff%' and h.AdmissionDate between '18/02/2013' and '18/02/2013') as Admission from Division d, mate a where d.Active= 1 and a.Active =1
```

Comment: Isn't it already doing what you want? It's testing conditions on two different tables.

Comment: why are your joins in a sub query and you outer query using those joins?

Comment: if im not mistaken, yes you can

Comment: my question is based on the 2nd and last part of the line..can i do like that, to combine 2 tables for my from clause and where clause to display the Active staff?..correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yeah, but you need to give some way to join the two tables. If the two tables actually has exactly the same columns, you need to merge the two tables.

Comment: Please, provide (edit your original question) your table definitions, sample data, and desired output, so that we won't guess what is it really you want us to help you with.

Comment: i have edit my original question..error display is that **bold**Invalid column name 'Active'**bold**.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can give comparison between any number of tables in where clause provided you are giving valid conditions inside your where clause. I think you should refer [SQL JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many as you want clauses inside the WHERE from your SQL query..

see an example

```
SELECT *
FROM employee inner join department on
    employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
WHERE 
    employee.active = TRUE AND
    department.group = 3
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join